# Using TKinter text tags with regex capturing groups

Tags: python, regex, tkinter, syntax-highlighting, capturing-group

I'm writing a text editor in Python TKinter, and am currently working on syntax.  I am trying to make it underline text in the format:

```
\_ **UNDER line This text 0!** \_  (underline the bolded text)
```

I'm using using regex commands such as : `text.search("\_ [a-zA-Z0-9 !]+ \_", ...)` currently.  However, this will underline the underscores and the spaces between the underscores and the text, also.  I don't want this.  I was thinking of using capturing groups to fix this, but don't know how to do so with TKinter.  I'm currently trying: `text.search("\_ ([a-zA-Z0-9 !]+) \_", ...)`, but that doesn't work.

Any ideas how I would address this problem?

Comment: I don't think the `Text.search()` method's regexp capabilities are sophisticated enough to do this. What you could do instead is use it with the `count` option to retrieve _all_ the text of interest and then use the `re` module to further process subgroups in what it returns.

Comment: Did you try look-behind and look-ahead to exclude the underscores with spaces? `text.search("(?<=\_ )([a-zA-Z0-9 !]+)(?= \_)", ...)` ?

Comment: @stribizhev: that's not a syntax the text widget supports. This must be a regular expression that Tcl understands - see http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm#M29

Comment: Then I think this post can be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19464813/explain-tkinter-text-search-method