# Read one line at a time from tkinter textbox

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter.text

I can read one line at a time, from an input box, and display it in a new box, but I need to advance to the next line of code.

Here are the text boxes in the GUI

```
    self.sourcecode = Text(master, height=8, width=30)
    self.sourcecode.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)

    self.nextline = Button(master, text="Next Line", fg="orange", command=lambda:[self.nextLine(self.intcount), self.lexicalResult()])
    self.nextline.grid(row=12, column=1, sticky=E)

    self.lexicalresult = Text(master, height=8, width=30)
    self.lexicalresult.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky=W)
```

These are my functions to copy from one box, to the other (output would `insert()` into the `lexicalResult()` function)

```
def nextLine (self, intcount):
    print("Reading from source")
    self.linenumber.delete('1.0', END)
    self.intcount = self.intcount + 1
    self.linenumber.insert('0.0', self.intcount)
    self.retrieve_input()

def retrieve_input(self):
    lines = self.sourcecode.get('1.0', '2.0') #I need to take this and move to the next line but i am new to python and don't know what functions there are or their arguments
    self.lexicalresult.insert('1.0', lines)

def lexicalResult (self):
    print("Printing to result")
```

Comment: What happens when you run that code? What does it do, and how is it different from what you expect?

Comment: @BryanOakley If I enter two lines of source code into the sourcecode box, it outputs both of the lines on the same line of the result box, with just a space in between. I want it it read one line, then print one line, then repeat

Comment: Use either this [explain-tkinter-text-search-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19464813/explain-tkinter-text-search-method) or get the whole `sourcecode` and do `split('\n')`

Comment: Split worked great thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can read a single line of text by using the "lineend" modifier on an index. For example, to get all of line 1 you could use something like this:

```
text.get("1.0", "1.0 lineend")
```

That will get everything on the line *except the trailing newline*. If you want the trailing newline, get just one character more:

```
text.get("1.0", "1.0 lineend+1c")
```

To delete an entire line you could use the very same indexes and pass them to the `delete` method.

As a more general purpose rule, given any index, to compute the beginning of the next line you can use something like this:

```
next_line = text.index("{} lineend+1c".format(index))
```

The `index` method converts an index into it's canonical form. The "lineend" modifier changes the index to the end of the line, and `+1c` moves it one character further.